# How do i install rails application from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i have my application source code on github, now i want to upload it to my server. Should i first run `rails new blog` and then do a git init and git pull? Or do i have to create a folder manually, do a git pull to it and no need for `rails new blog` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first you want to git clone that repo from git hub

`git clone blaa@github.com/blaa`

once you get a folder created, go there and try doing

`bundle`

once that's done and once your dependencies are resolved, you can start the server

`rails server`

Comment: Hi denniss, thank you for your quick reply. Will that work if i have a passenger with multiple virtual hosts?

Comment: If you have multiple virtual hosts, I believe you need your code to live in each of your host. The process of cloning the project should be the same. Unless you need to configure something differently for each host. I could be wrong about this.